# Instead of NULL, should I write `0x0` or `0`?

Tags: c++, null

I know that you are supposed to use `0` instead of NULL in c++ (even though `NULL` is defined as `0` in C++ most of the time).

Recently I came across some code where `0x0` was used instead, though.

What is the difference?

Comment: Who says you're supposed to use 0 instead of NULL?  Personally, I think you should use "(void*)0".

Comment: @Paul: `(void*)0` will not work similarly in C++. C++ compilers get angry when they see something like: `int* x = (void*)0;` while `int* x = 0;` is OK.

Comment: Yeah, I was more opining about the design of the language than suggesting you actually do it that way.

Comment: @Paul: Not allowing implicit conversion of `void*` to other pointer types is one place where C++ broke compatibility with C (and for a reason).

Comment: @Paul: "I think you should use" "I was more [..] than suggesting you actually do it that way"

Answer (score 29):

`0x0` is just `0` written in hexadecimal notation. There is no difference between the two:

> 0<sub>16</sub> = 0<sub>10</sub> :)

`NULL` is usually `#define`d to `0` somewhere and does the same thing.

Comment: And `= 0_8`, which is what the question asks about.

Comment: Also, as `0b0`(binary) and `00`(octal). Although, most compilers' preprocessor changes these to 0.

Answer (score 19):

There is no difference. In C, NULL is often defined to be `(void *)0`, but in C++ that's not allowed. A few ancient compilers got this wrong, but they really are ancient.

IMO, it's better to use NULL, as it portrays the *intent* more clearly, and gives you a nice, easy symbol to S&R when your compiler gets updated to C++ 0x, which will include `nullptr`.

Comment: +1.  Up to very recently I was party to using 0 instead of NULL, but the inclusion of `nullptr` in C++0x made me change my mind.

Answer (score 8):

By the way, everyone,

0x0 is hex, as you have all mentioned, but

0 is Octal, not decimal! :-)

ie any number starting with 0 (and not followed by x) is octal:

```
0 = 0
01 = 1
02 = 2
...
07 = 7
010 = 8
011 = 9
012 = 10
...
```

:-)

Comment: I was going to down vote you for sowing confusion.  But I had to check the standard first ... and you're right.  Learn something new everyday (not that this is worth remembering, but I will anyways).

Comment: that's exactly how it lives in my brain - I know it is totally useless, but yet I remember it.

Comment: Correct, but not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 6):

`0x0` and `0` represent the same value, so you can use the one that best suits your eye.  When we get C++0x, we'll have the keyword `nullptr` to represent null pointers of any type.

Answer (score 2):

0x0 is just an expression of the value 0 in hexadecimal. I doubt the compiler will care about the difference.

Answer (score 2):

No difference

In my opinion, 0x0 is more explicit.

Some people may confuse 0 with "0"(0x30 -I´ve seen it happen).

Comment: 0x0000 is even more explicit!

Comment: @Roger: nah, that's only more explicit on a 16bit machine. On a 32bit machine it's still not explicit enough ;-)

Comment: +1 for giving me a laugh. But if you are running a 64 bit compiler you should use 0x0000000000000000 for maximum explicitness.

Comment: Actually, on a 64 bit machine it may make sense to define NULL as 0LL, so `sizeof(NULL)==sizeof((void*)NULL)`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, its a matter of taste. People like to write memory addresses in hexa decimal, so writing NULL as 0x0 would be more classic. For ordinary ones like me, 0 will suffice.

Answer (score -8):

So, this site has some really good information on NULL: http://c-faq.com/null/index.html

NULL is actually the "null pointer" - so it might be of type, for example, "(void*)0". This tells the compiler that NULL is not to be treated as an int, but rather as a "pointer to an int". And in C, the compiler will give warnings/errors if the types don't match.

The value "0" and "0x0" are equivalent in C++. Whenever a number is prefixed by "0x", it means that that value is the hexadecimal representation of that number. For example, 0x5 == 5.

Also, 0xA [in hexadecimal, base 16) == 10 [in base 10].

**edit**

Here are some sources. In glibc, NULL seems to be defined differently in different places. (why should this be?)

[#define NULL ((void *)0)](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/libc/stdlib/gmp-impl.h?revision=1.9.4.1&root=libc&view=markup) (stdlib/gmp-impl.h)

[#define NULL 0](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/libc/posix/getopt1.c?root=libc&view=markup) (posix/getopt1.c)

**edit2**

well, it looks like i've missed the mark on this one! sorry! (CW'd. feel free to keep downvoting!)

Comment: In C++, NULL will not be (for example) "(void*)0" -- that's clearly not allowed. Though it's probably a typo, that would be treated as point to void, not pointer to int.

Comment: This answer is wrong. NULL is not the "null pointer". It merely converts to a "null pointer" of a particular type. Also you are linking to a C site on a C++ question. (even in C, NULL is not necessarily a "null pointer").

Comment: Notice that your linked site says "NULL is defined as a null pointer constant" - *not* as a null pointer!